# Limiting choices from an intermediary ManyToMany junction table in Django

Tags: django, django-models, data-modeling

### Background

I've created three Django models—Inventory, SalesOrder, and Invoice—to model items in inventory, sales orders for those items, and invoices for a particular sales order. Each sales order can have multiple items, so I've used an intermediary junction table—`SalesOrderItems`—using the `through` argument for the `ManyToManyField`. Also, partial billing of a sales orders is allowed, so I've created a `ForeignKey` in the `Invoice` model related to the `SalesOrder` model, so that a particular sales order can have multiple  invoices.

Here's where I deviate from what I've normally seen. Instead of relating the `Invoice` model to the `Item` model via a `ManyToManyField`, I've related the `Invoice` model to the `SalesOrderItem` intermediary junction table through the intermediary junction table `InvoiceItem`. I've done this because it better models reality—our invoices are tied to sales orders and can only include items that are tied to that sales order as opposed to any item in inventory. I will admit that it does seem strange having the intermediary junction table of a `ManyToManyField` related to the intermediary junction table of another `ManyToManyField`.

### Questions

- Is there a better way to model the relationship of only allowing items on an invoice to be those items that are associated with the invoice's sales order?
- Is the model the correct place to include the logic to limit the invoice items to only those items that are associated with the invoice's sales order? IMO, the answer is "yes" given that the [Django documentation][dj-model-doc] describes a model as "the single, definitive source of data about your data."
- How can I limit the choices available for the `invoice_items` in the `Invoice` model to just the `sales_order_items` of the `SalesOrder` model for that particular `Invoice` regardless of accessing the model via the admin pages or a form?

### Code

```
class Item(models.Model):
    item_num = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    default_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2,
        blank=True, null=True)

class SalesOrderItem(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item)
    sales_order = models.ForeignKey('SalesOrder')
    unit_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    quantity = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=4)

class SalesOrder(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Party)
    so_num = models.SlugField(max_length=40, unique=True)
    sales_order_items = models.ManyToManyField(Item, 
        through=SalesOrderItem)

class InvoiceItem(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(SalesOrderItem)
    invoice = models.ForeignKey('Invoice')
    unit_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    quantity = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=4)

class Invoice(models.Model):
    invoice_num = models.SlugField(max_length=25)
    sales_order = models.ForeignKey(SalesOrder)
    invoice_items = models.ManyToManyField(SalesOrderItem,
        through='InvoiceItem')
```

Answer (score 1):

`limit_choices_to` only affects the admin pages. If you want to change the available choices in a normal ModelForm then you'll need to modify the [`queryset`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField.queryset) attribute of the form field.

Comment: It seems to me that the logic to limit the choices for the InvoiceItems should be handled in the model as opposed to in a form. Whether it be in the admin pages, form, or anywhere, I only want InvoiceItems for a particular Invoice to be able to select the SalesItems for the Invoice's SalesOrder.

Comment: In Django 1.3 limit_choices_to also applies to the 'ordinary' relations, not just the admin.